# Vulkan - Descriptor Set на каждый объект (или нет?)

Tags: c++, графика, vulkan

Решил разобраться с Vulkan, и столкнулся с одним недопониманием. В Vulkan есть такое понятие как дескрипторы (точнее наборы дескрипторов - DescriptorSet). Они описывают доступ к каким-либо ресурсам (буферам, изображениям) из шейдеров. При этом, наборы дескрипторов выделяются из дескрипторного пула (DescriptorPool), и при создании дескрипторного пула нужно указывать какое конкретно кол-во дескрипторных наборов можно выделить из этого пула (maxSets).

Затем, когда мы уже записываем команды в командный буфер, мы привязываем дескрипторный набор (который связан с конкретным ресурсами), привязываем буферы вершин и индексов, а затем вызываем команду рисования.

**И вот тут возникает вопрос**

Если рассуждать таким образом, что на каждый объект (меш) есть свой дескрипторный набор, который привязываем перед отрисовкой этого объекта, получается, чтобы каждый объект мог обладать, например, своим собственным материалом (текстурами и прочими значениями), нужно для каждого объекта аллоцировать свой Descriptor Set? Если это так - то откуда можно знать максимальное количество этих самых дескрипторных наборов, при создании пула, если не известно сколько мне потребуется объектов на сцене? Может быть я не правильно рассуждаю, и дескрипторный набор может быть один для всех этих объектов, просто перед отрисовкой каждого объекта нужно делать обновление набора `vkUpdateDescriptorSets`? Или свой набор на каждый объект - это вполне нормально, и можно просто с запасом задать maxSets при создании пула?

**И второй момент**

Есть еще такой тип дескриптора, как "динамический UBO буфер", и когда мы привязываем дескрипторный набор с таким буфером, то мы указываем динамическое смещение:

```
// Набор динамических смещений для набора с динамическим дескриптором
std::vector<uint32_t> dynamicOffsets = {
    primitiveIndex * static_cast<uint32_t>(this->device_.GetDynamicAlignment<glm::mat4>())
};

// Набор дескрипторов, которые привязываем
std::vector<VkDescriptorSet> descriptorSets = {
    descriptorSetMain
};

// Привязать наборы дескрипторов
vkCmdBindDescriptorSets(
    commandBuffers[i], 
    VK_PIPELINE_BIND_POINT_GRAPHICS, 
    pipelineLayout, 
    0, 
    (uint32_t)descriptorSets.size(),
    descriptorSets.data(), 
    (uint32_t)dynamicOffsets.size(), 
    dynamicOffsets.data());

// Привязать буфер вершин
VkDeviceSize offsets[1] = { 0 };
vkCmdBindVertexBuffers(commandBuffers[i], 0, 1, &(primitives[primitiveIndex].vertexBuffer.vkBuffer), offsets);

// Привязать буфер индексов
vkCmdBindIndexBuffer(commandBuffers[i], primitives[primitiveIndex].indexBuffer.vkBuffer, 0, VK_INDEX_TYPE_UINT32);

// Отрисовка геометрии
vkCmdDrawIndexed(commandBuffers[i], primitives[primitiveIndex].indexBuffer.count, 1, 0, 0, 0);
```

Здесь получается, что перед каждым рисованием объекта, я привязываю как бы один и тот же дескрипторный набор, но благодаря смещению, в шейдере во время рисования очередного меша, привязке соответствует своя часть буфера, связанного с дескриптором. Но возникает вопрос - если можно (***если это допустимо и правильно***) аллоцировать на каждый объект свой дескрипторный набор, в чем смысл подхода с динамическим смещением? А если это все таки ***НЕ допустимо или не правильно***, и нельзя выделять особо много наборов, то почему аналогичную штуку нельзя проворачивать с текстурными дескрипторами? Хотелось бы просто понять как это всё делать правильно.

Заранее спасибо.